# How to write an NSArray of UIImage objects to file?

Tags: file, uiimage, save, nsarray, nskeyedarchiver

I have been attempting to use NSMutableArray's writeToFile:atomically:

But it has been pointed out to me that this approach is wrong: i.e. [iPhone / Objective-C: NSMutableArray writeToFile won't write to file. Always returns NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767465/iphone-objective-c-nsmutablearray-writetofile-wont-write-to-file-always-retu)

It looks like I'm going to have to read the guide on archiving that is referred to in one of the answers in the above link.

Would anyone care to share (or point me towards) some code that helps me accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

The method, you've mentioned recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the file.

Try this:

```
for (UIImage *image in arrayWithImages) {
    NSString *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", @"nameOfTheImage.png"]];
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Maybe you can use `[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];` to write image as jpeg.

Comment: I think this is what I will do, manually iterate through saving each image.  PS welcome to S O :]