# How can we add NSMutableDictionary with Image as object in NSMutableArray and write this array in Plist

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsmutablearray, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I want to store UIImage in NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture.image);
[studDict setValue:imgData forKey:@"Photo"];
```

where,
**studDict** is NSMutableDictionary.
and **picture** is UIImageView.

and store this dictionnary add as object in NSMutableArray.

```
    [studArrayPlist addObject:detailDict];
```

where,
**studArrayPlist** is NSMutableArray.
and **detailDict** is NSMutableDictionary with UIImage.

and this NSMutableArray write in plist.

```
[studArrayPlist writeToFile:plistPath atomically: TRUE];
```

where,
**studArrayPlist** is NSMutableArray store NSMutableDictionary with UIImage.

This will not work not write in plist.
and dont give any error.
Also i want to retrive all the data in array from plist.

Comment: try putting "studArrayPlist" into another dictionary and then write that dictionary to a plist because u can write only dictionaries(root object) to plist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767465/iphone-objective-c-nsmutablearray-writetofile-wont-write-to-file-always-ret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the object is added to the dictionary & array.If not then allocate NSMutableArray & NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *studDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[studDict setValue:imgData forKey:@"Photo"];

NSMutableArray * studArrayPlist =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[studArrayPlist addObject:studDict];
[studArrayPlist writeToFile: plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i'm doing this and it woks properly but work slowly sometimes.

Now,
for storing image as data

```
NSMutableDictionary *studDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture.image);
[studDict setValue:imgData forKey:@"Photo"];

NSMutableArray * studArrayPlist =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[studArrayPlist addObject:studDict];
[studArrayPlist writeToFile: plistPath atomically:YES];
```

and for retriving image as data,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// get the path to our Data/plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StudDetail.plist"];

//Storing all the records (NSDictionary objects) in array from plist.
studeInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[studeInfo objectAtIndex:"your index"] objectForKey:@"Photo"]];
[person setImage:img];
[img release];
```